# display user profile image with yahoo open id

Tags: php

Is there any way to show user profile image when he login with yahoo openid?
I want to show user profile image on my site when he login with yahoo openid

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OpenID-General-Discussion/Get-Fetch-email-and-other-profile-info/1272016054000-0dfe8736-5c46-3c83-a4ac-c38d25722e3b

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through standard API http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OpenID-General-Discussion/Get-Fetch-email-and-other-profile-info/1272016054000-0dfe8736-5c46-3c83-a4ac-c38d25722e3b